# opening a file for reading content

Tags: python, file

I am following Python tutorials ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)) on **files**.

I have a simple text file, containing 3 lines. According to the tutorial page, putting this simple snippet in a file and executing the script should display the contents, but it does not.

```
f = open('myFile.txt', 'r')
f.read()
f.readline()
f.close()
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: How would you see its content without `print f.readline()`

Comment: you haven't printed the output.

Comment: Thanks guys. got it!

Comment: The tutorial is to blame. It uses Python's Immediate Mode, where the result of every command is printed immediately - but does not mention that.

Comment: Yeah, after a while I realized there was never any printing commands! But I am improving now. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```py
fp = open(r"d:\test.txt")
print ( fp.read() )
fp.close()
```